# How to use google.protobuf.Any type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, grpc-web

## 1.the protocol buffer 3 file test.proto

```proto
option go_package = ".;apps";
package apps;

message ShardKvMap{
  map<string, google.protobuf.Any> data = 1;
}
```

## 2.i use grpc-web build .ts file

```
protoc -I=$DIR test.proto \
  --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:$OUT_DIR \
  --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcwebtext:$OUT_DIR
```

## 3.How to use google.protobuf.Any type in typescript?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot help you with the build-in JS and TS support, but I can tell you how to do it with the [protobuf-ts plugin](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts) (I am the author).

```js
// this creates an empty new message
let msg = ShardKvMap.create();

// this packs the empty new message into an Any message, 
// and adds it to map under the key "foo":
msg.data["foo"] = Any.pack(msg, ShardKvMap);
```

As far as I know, protobuf-ts is the only library out there for JavaScript / TypeScript that fully supports google.protobuf.Any, including JSON format. Here is the section about Any support in the [manual](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts/blob/v1.0.0/MANUAL.md#googleprotobufany).

Comment: What pros does your lib have? Why should we use it instead of https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js and https://github.com/stephenh/ts-proto ?

Comment: I wrote protobuf-ts because ts-proto and protobuf.js's support for well-known-types, code size in a web application and conformance with the protobuf spec was not sufficient for me.